# linq join in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, join

I am new to mvc :)

I try to show a join but was not successfull .

I put below method in Model

```
LinqDataContext db = new LinqDataContext();
    public IQueryable getExam()
    {
        return from exam in db.Exam_Table
               join cat in db.Cat_Table
               on
               exam.Exam_Cat_ID_FK equals cat.Cat_ID

               select new { exam, cat };        

    }
```

and call it from controller by below code :

```
   exam_rep exrep = new exam_rep();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var exams=exrep.getExams();
        return View(exams);
    }
```

but can not display it in view by below code :

```
foreach(var ex in Model)
{
%>
  <tr>
  <td><%: ex.exam.Exam_Title %></td>
  </tr>

<%   
}
%>
```

how should I display values in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't the objects linked by the linq datacontext?

I think it would be something like this:

```
db.Exams.Select(e => new { Exam = e, Cat = e.Cat });
```

Or Linq syntax

```
from e in db.Exams select new { Exam = e, Cat = e.Cat };
```

Or Simply

```
// assuming Exam.Cat
return db.Exams
```

I would look at your datacontext and make sure you have it setup correctly. It seems like you might be over complicating things.